# Walking Both Ways of The Inheritance Chain

Tags: java, inheritance

Sorry if I do a bad job of phrasing this, I'm trying my best. In Object Oriented programming, the `is-a` relationship is commonly used in discussions (talked about? not sure how to say it). However, is there ever a useful purpose in going up the inheritance chain? Starting from the child, then walking all the way back up? The only situation I can think of is something like this:

```
public class A {
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println("Hi, from A");
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println("Hi, from B");
    }
}
public class C extends B{
    //no overriden version for C
}
```

Here, you walk up the chain to find the closest version of `sayHi` there is, which for object `myObject` would be residing in `B`

```
A myObject = new C();
myObject.sayHi(); //Hi, from B
```

Are there any other useful ways of analyzing relationships while walking up the inheritance chain?

**NOTE:**

Although it may not have an impact, I'm asking this question from a Java frame of mind

Comment: _Starting from the child, then walking all the way back up_ All the way is really only to a direct subtype. For example, if you had overriden the method in `C`, you would not be able to get `A`'s implementation through `C`.

Comment: Yeah, my question is what are the uses of walking up the inheritance chain? The example I gave is calling the right method off an object, but are there any other uses? @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, that may have been unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be useful when you need to analyze metadata attached to a superclass.

For two concrete examples, database classes (such as JPA entities and Spring Data documents) frequently have some core metadata, such as the MongoDB collection to use, on the base class, along with additional information on concrete subclasses. Additionally, service objects (such as Spring MVC controllers) may have mappings or security annotations listed on a base class. The container needs to walk up the hierarchy to merge the appropriate rules in either case.